# How to put validation on text field not allow characters while paste in ext js

Tags: extjs

How to put validation on text field not allow characters while paste in ext js?

I am using maskRe: /[0-9]/.
Using this while entering value only digits are allowed.
But while paste it allows character.

Comment: which version of extjs you are using?

Comment: I am using 3.4.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

In Ext JS 3.4 you have to manage this by your custom code.You can do this, It removes text when you will remove focus from field.

```
blur: function (field) {
    if (isNaN(field.getRawValue())) {
    this.reset();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check the input value on the "blur" event :

```
myTextField.on('blur', function (component) {
    if (!component.isValid()) {
         // Do what you need to do, maybe clear the TextField ?
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it will for 3.4.1 or not.But we used the following code in 4.2 version.

We used `render` & `change` events of the textfield,to achieve this.

We used `render` to capture paste event on its DOM element & set the type of field as `onpaste`.

We used `change` & checked if type is `onpaste`.Then we extracted the `maskRe` of field & used `replace()` to remove unwanted characters as per the `maskRe`

Here is a **[working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/u6g)**.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
       Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Contact Info',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Telephone No.',
        maskRe:/[0-9]/,
        allowBlank: false,
          listeners: {
            render: function (field) {
                    field.getEl().on('paste', function () {
                        this.type = 'onpaste';
                    }, field);
            },
              change:function(field){
                  if (field.type == 'onpaste' && field.maskRe) {
            field.type = null;
            var regex = new RegExp(field.maskRe.toString().replace('/[', '[^').replace(']/', ']').replace('[^^', '['), 'g');
            field.setValue(field.getValue().replace(regex, ''));
        }
              }
        }
    }]
});
    }
});
```

For Ext 3.4.1, we can use following code.But it remove the unwanted characters only after blur.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    // turn on validation errors beside the field globally
    Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';
    var bd = Ext.getBody();
    var simple = new Ext.FormPanel({
        labelWidth: 75, // label settings here cascade unless overridden
        frame: true,
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 350,
        defaults: { width: 230 },
        defaultType: 'textfield',

        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Telphone No.',
            name: 'telephone',
            maskRe: /[0-9]/,
            allowBlank: false,
            listeners: {
                render: function (field) {
                    field.getEl().on('paste', function () {
                        this.type = 'onpaste';
                    }, field);
                },
                change: function (field) {
                    if (field.type == 'onpaste' && field.maskRe) {
                        field.type = null;
                        var regex = new RegExp(field.maskRe.toString().replace('/[', '[^').replace(']/', ']').replace('[^^', '['), 'g');
                        field.setValue(field.getValue().replace(regex, ''));
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    });

    simple.render(document.body);


});
```